# Using a C++ std::vector as a queue in a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I would like to have items added to a queue in one thread via in an asynchronous web request handler:

```
void handleRequest(item) {
    toProcess.push_back(item);
}
```

There is a background thread that constantly processes these queue items as follows:

```
while(true) {
   for(auto item : toProcess) { doSomething(item); }
   toProcess.clear();
}
```

Clearly this isn't thread safe ... you might add an item to toProcess right when the for loop finishes and thus have it cleared out without being processed. What would be the best model to program something like this?

Comment: [`std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) is not an option?

Comment: Both threads need to synchronise, for example by using a `mutex`.  Each locks the mutex before doing operations that resize the vector (or queue), and releases that mutex when done.   That ensures each thread waits while the other thread is holding the mutex.   Part of the design consideration is granularity - for example, does one thread grab and release the mutex for a single operation (e.g. adding or removing a value) or multiple operations (add multiple values, process then clear all values).

Comment: This seems the poster-child for a queue, mutex, and condition variable trio. Both producers and consumers of the queue need to use all three to co-mingle safely.

Comment: There is also the option to use a lock-free queue instead of a mutex. But be aware, this may sound more efficient but depending on granularity (frequency of pushs / pops, job timing etc) and load it may be slower than using a mutex. Lock-free data structures improve scalability, but in a simple producer-consumer example the overhead of mutexes can be very low, especially on OS with cheap user-space futexes.

Comment: `std::vector` is only useful for a queue when you have a fixed-size ring buffer.  If you need a queue-like container that supports random access iterators, use `std::deque`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to use [`std::atomic<T>::wait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/wait) which is a `C++20` feature, there is a way to do it with [condition variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) too however, and they exist since `C++11`.

Include `<atomic>` and `<mutex>`

You will need a member atomic_bool.
`std::atomic_bool RequestPassed = false;`
and a member mutex
`std::mutex RequestHandleMutex;`

Your handleRequest function would then become

```cpp
void handleRequest(item) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(RequestHandleMutex)
    toProcess.push_back(item);
    RequestPassed.store(true);
    RequestPassed.notify_all();
}
```

and your loop would be this

```cpp
while(true) {
    RequestPassed.wait(false);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(RequestHandleMutex)
    /* handle latest item passed */
    RequestPassed.store(false);
}
```

This way, the while thread waits instead of constantly iterating (saving cpu power and battery). If you then use `handleRequest`, the atomic_bool gets notified to stop waiting, the request is handled (mutex is locked so no new requests can come while this happens),  RequestPassed is reset to false, and the thread waits for the next request.